# How to convert a data frame to a big matrix fast with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` with 4211 rows and 1 column:

```
     bow
0   [(6,1),(8,3),(9,1),...]   
1   [(1,1),(3,1),(10,1),...]   
2   [(9,2),(12,3),(13,1),...]
...
```

Each row represents a document and the list in `bow` is the `word id` and their corresponding `occurrence times` in that document, in a bag-of-words format. For instance, in the first document, the word with `id 6` has occurred one time, and the word with `id 8` has occurred 3 times. There are totally `5000` words and `4211` documents.
Now I'd like to convert this data frame to a big `doc-word` matrix, with size of `4211` * `5000`. `m_ij=n` denotes the word with id `i` occurs `n` times in document `j`. How can I implement it fast? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried just iterating the series and assign the value. And it took just one or two seconds.

Comment: please provide desired output for the data set you have posted in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to numpy arrays should speed it up (but I haven't tested it on data of your type and size).

I assume that `word id`s don't appear more than once in a single row.

```
# 1. allocating space for the output array:
output_arr = np.zeros(shape = (len(df), 5000), dtype = int)
# 2. converting DF to np.array (arr_df will be of shape (len(df),1)):
arr_df = np.array(df)
# 3. iterating:
for i in range(len(arr_df)):
    # arr_df[i] is a np.array containing a list so we have to use arr_df[i][0] to get to the tuples:
    idx, values = zip(*arr_df[i][0])
    output_arr[i,idx] = val
```